# Redirect to different link depending on date

Tags: javascript, date, redirect

I have done some research, but I can't quite find what I'm looking for.

Basically, I just want to change a redirect depending on a certain date. It's for an advent calendar, so users will click on "See our advent calendar" link, and depending on the date (December 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ...) they will see a different web page for each day of December.

I thought it might be something simple like:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var currentDate = new Date().getDate();
if (currentDate = 2014,11,26)
  window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com";
else if (currentDate = 2014,11,27)
  window.location = "http://www.youtube.com";
else if (currentDate = 2014,10,28)
  window.location = "http://www.google.com";
</script>
```

(I'd replace Google/youtube/etc with my actual links, but no matter what date it is, it just goes to the first link)
I've tried different date formats including YYYY/MM/DD, and Year/month/day/hour/second/millisecond.

I apologize if this is stupidly easy to do and I'm missing something obvious. But you learn by asking...

Comment: `<script language="javascript">` is deprecated.

Comment: Also instead of making different pages try sending a get variable with the url (`http://www.yahoo.com?whatever=whatever`) and have the page display different things based on the get variable. You can accomplish it with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've the location part which is good. It is the comparison part where your code is lacking.. You can do this

```
var date = new Date()  // construct a Date instance
           .toISOString()  // convert into ISO time
           .split('T')[0]; // this will result in "2013-11-26"
if(date == "your date in the format year-month-day here"){
   window.location.href = "your url here";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit Joki for the speedy reply! Got it working! Much help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your if statements you are assignen with the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==` which always results in the statement to be true. Next, the `.getDate()` function only returns the day of month as a Number.
For an advent calendar that is enough, so you can use that like this:

```
var currentDate = new Date().getDate();
if (currentDate == 26)
    window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com";
else if (currentDate == 27)
    window.location = "http://www.youtube.com";
else if (currentDate == 28)
    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

But a better way to realize your goal would be to use an array, with the links you want to redirect to in it and just use the day to pick the link, because otherwise you have 24 if statements in your code. You can do this like this:

```
var links = ["http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.youtube.com", "http://www.google.com"];
var currentDate = new Date().getDate();
window.location = links[currentDate-1];
```

this is an easy solution for an advent calendar